# Facebook OAuth 2.0 and https redirect URL

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am making a site like www.firstcovers.com and have a little confusion about https with OAuth 2.0 facebook redirect URL.
After getting the access token in [code] the redirect URL with it which is pointing back to your site should be **https** or **http** for websites (not canvas apps)?

Please clear my confusion.
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-canvas apps you can [use both](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/). The only requirement for it is that:

> the redirect_uri must have the same base domain as that specified in the App Domain property of your app's settings

However not, that the `code` value is not the *access token*, but the *authorization code*! You still have to exchange it for an `access token`, see the section [4. Exchange the code for a User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).